# How can I make android app (webview) which sends push notification when rss feeds updates?

Tags: android, webview, push-notification, rss

How can I make android app (webview) which sends push notification when rss feeds updates ?
Is it possible to build app like this.
I run a Q&A website and I have developed a webview for my website but how can I add push notifications to it when rss feed updates (mean new question is asked by someone).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using Webview, if you are using php with mysql, 
use "HttpUrlConnection" and "Json" to send and receive Data. it goes like,

```
Url url = new Url("http://www.example.com/abc.php");
HttpUrlConnection conn = (HttpUrlConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

OutputStreme output = new OutputStreme(conn.getOutputStreme);//for sending Data to php
InputStreme input = new InputStreme(conn.getInputStreme);//for receiving Data from php
output.close;
input.close;
```

If you want to show notification run "Async Task" it runs in background and make a frequent request to database by POST method if there's any change show a notification
(from android 8.0 notifications require CHANNEL_ID, make sure you check it out).

Comment: Yeah I am using php with mysql. I have this thing installed https://www.question2answer.org/qa/

Comment: by using the above method you don't want any other sdk and its simple and secure and modifiable

Comment: Can you please tell me where should I put that code in android studio webview source code ? I am not a developer